# import parent and sub category with csv magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, import, csv, importexport

I am uploading a CSV in Magento 1.9, and what i need is to import both categories and sub-categories, but now it is currently importing only sub-categories. Here is an example of how I the categories are defined.

Sports & Fitness /Fitness Accessories

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 1.x, there are many free modules which can help to import categories.

http://www.magentoworks.net/import_categories.zip

Please check above link for reference.

I have used this extension in Magento 1.8 and 1.9 versions and found it useful.